# terminology for grouping words in a string?

Tags: terminology, strings, substrings

We commonly create sub-groups of strings in one particular algorithm implementation. I just want to know in CS literature is there any standard name for such kind of grouping. For e.g.

```
Hello World! This is May from the dairy farm.
```

Strings with sub-groups of two:

```
Hello World!
World! This
This is
is May
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for the term [n-grams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram), with $n = 2$ in your case. This is very useful in natural language processing and speech recognition.